# TypeScript: array destructuring from awaited Promise compiles and crash at runtime

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get the [ResultSet from the executeSql](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native-sqlite-storage/index.d.ts#L64) function of the [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage)
 library, but I get `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

The `executeSql` function should return a `Promise<[Transaction, ResultSet]>`, and I can't seem to get the destructuring right.

My code: `database.ts`:

```
let conn = SQLite.openDatabase({name: DATABASE_NAME, location: 'default'})

export default class Db  {
  static async getConn() {
    return await conn
  }

  static async getTransaction() {
    return new Promise<Transaction>(async (resolve,reject) => {
      const conn = await this.getConn()
      conn.transaction((transaction: Transaction) => {
        resolve(transaction)
      })
    })
  }

  static async executeSql(sqlStatement: string, args?: any[]) {
    return new Promise<ResultSet>(async (resolve,reject) => {
      const transaction = await this.getTransaction()
      const [tr, results] = await transaction.executeSql(sqlStatement, args)  // ??
      resolve(results)
    })
  }
}
```

Compiled:

```
Db.executeSql = function (sqlStatement, args) {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
        var _this = this;
        return __generator(this, function (_a) {
            return [2 /*return*/, new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { return __awaiter(_this, void 0, void 0, function () {
                    var transaction, _a, tr, results;
                    return __generator(this, function (_b) {
                        switch (_b.label) {
                            case 0: return [4 /*yield*/, this.getTransaction()];
                            case 1:
                                transaction = _b.sent();
                                return [4 /*yield*/, transaction.executeSql(sqlStatement, args)];
                            case 2:
                                _a = _b.sent(), tr = _a[0], results = _a[1];  // <= ERROR HERE: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
                                resolve(results);
                                return [2 /*return*/];
                        }
                    });
                }); })];
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the code, (https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage/blob/master/lib/sqlite.core.js#L449), `transaction.executeSql` doesn't return a Promise. It actually doesn't return anything.

It also appears that the method takes a `success` and `error` callback, so your code should be something like:

```
static async executeSql(sqlStatement: string, args?: any[]) {
    const transaction = await this.getTransaction();
    const [tr, results] = await new Promise<ResultSet>(
      (resolve,reject) =>           
        transaction.executeSql(sqlStatement, args,
          (t, r) => resolve([t, r]), 
          (err) => reject(err)
        )
    );
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I should have dug that way. So we agree that `executeSql(sqlStatement: string, arguments?: any[]): Promise<[Transaction, ResultSet]>;` should not be in the types file?

Comment: Thanks, but you're not answering the issue here. I already know how to use the callback version of the api. The issue is why many of the definitions in the types file on DefinitelyTyped are completely wrong. My final solution is to rewrite the types file from scratch.

Comment: You can always contribute and fix the typings. They are created by the community. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native-sqlite-storage/index.d.ts I looked a bit over the code and it doesn't seem to have supported promises.